How to create a multi-node kubernetes cluster using VMs and port-forwarding
I can get multiple VMs from lambdalabs or tensordock and they give public IPs to each machine running each VM.
How to use kubeadm and create a master node on one VM and attach nodes (other VMs) to it? Although when it is created on the VM, it is created using the internal ip of the VM?
